# How can I formulate a standard APIs error response as an object in Loopback 4?

Tags: node.js, typescript, rest, loopback4

I am using Loopback4 to build REST APIs that can communicate directly with native mobile apps. As part f the error handling process what I need to do is formulating a standard error response with the following structure:

```
{
  code (Error code),
  errorName (Error Name),
  description (detailed description of the error)
}
```

This object will be sent to the native app in case any error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

`import {HttpErrors} from '@loopback/rest'`

then

`throw new HttpError[code](message)`
or 
`throw new HttpErrors.Forbidden('Invalid authorization');`

see more [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Controllers.html#handling-errors-in-controllers) on documentation